# Sending data from database using Jquery Ajax JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I restarted my old project and have a question regarding old code. 3 years ago I had this type of code to sent data from database to JavaScript arrays using php:

```
echo json_encode($result_array);
```

and JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "poli.php",
                    success : function(data) {
                        poli_owner = $.parseJSON(data);
                    },
                    async : false
                });
```

to populate JavaScript array.

My question is - is it still good code or not recommended anymore. If the code is not OK what code is better to use to take data from database and populate JavaScript array using php and JQuery? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is still good. All the web is still using Ajax and JSON.

Depending on your use case, you can load your data via a separate Ajax request, or just make your server-side language generate data for JS and include it in the page source code.

Comment: Thank you! I am bad at programming and know only this method so I will use it.